# Get radio value on change - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get radio's value `onChange` but it's giving me error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
<input className="tab-input" value="a" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" onChange={() => this.handleTabChange()} />
<label className="tab-label" htmlFor="tab1">Codepen</label>

<input className="tab-input" value="b" id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" onChange={() => this.handleTabChange()} />
<label className="tab-label" htmlFor="tab2">Dribbble</label>

<input className="tab-input" value="c" id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" onChange={() => this.handleTabChange()} />
<label className="tab-label" htmlFor="tab3">Dropbox</label>
```

Here is **handleTabChange** Code:

```
handleTabChange(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```

I have **bind** the function in constructor:

```
this.handleTabChange = this.handleTabChange.bind(this);
```

Don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Try this `onChange={this.handleTabChange}` in the input tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting event as a parameter, but you are not passing it.

This should solve it

```
<input className="tab-input" value="a" id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" onChange={(e) => this.handleTabChange(e)} />
```